# List is not being properly loaded in a reactjs program

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
state = {
    name: 'Teste II', 
    produto: null,
    alternativas: null,
    loading_produto: true,
    loading_alternativas: true,
    showPopup: false,
};

constructor( props ) {
    super( props );     
}

async componentDidMount(){
    const url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db857da3b0000770035f09b";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({produto: data.suggestions[0], loading_produto: false})
    this.setState({alternativas: data.choices, loading_alternativas: false})
    console.log(this.state.produto.product_data.title);
}

render() {

    const lista = this.state.alternativas;


    if(!this.state.loading_alternativas){

    this.texts = lista.map((text, key) => {
        console.log('chegou aqui');

        <li key={text.id}>{text.name}</li>
    });
}
return (...<ul>{this.texts}</ul>... )
```

It seems okay for me. Indeed, the code **"console.log('chegou aqui');"** is being executed. However the command 

"

  {this.texts}

"

 is not printing anything.

What is the problem?

Note that the API is being simulated by the link: [API](http://www.mocky.io/v2/5db857da3b0000770035f09b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `return`

```
this.texts = lista.map((text, key) => {
    console.log('chegou aqui');

    return (<li key={text.id}>{text.name}</li>)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I am starting to use it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `return` in the map function.

```
this.texts = lista.map((text, key) => {
    console.log('chegou aqui');

    return <li key={text.id}>{text.name}</li>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rerendering only happens on state or prop change

You're assigning class attributes to react elements. This is a no go in react. Render from the state like this

```
<ul>
{
  this.state.alternativas && this.state.alternativas.map((text, key) => <li key={text.id}>{text.name}</li>
}
</ul>
```